# Does the 'in' clause used on python dictionaries call the keys() function every time?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

Let's say I have a

```
dict = {...} #lots of words in dictionary
```

I have to do a

```
for word in ...: #long list of words
    if word in dict:
        #do something
```

My question is, does the 'if word in dict' call the dict.keys() function every time and hence a lot slower than if I added another variable at the top that is dict_keys = dict.keys()?  The result of what I am talking about would be this.

```
dict = {...}
dict_keys = dict.keys()

for word in ...:
    if word in dict_keys:
        #do something
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `for word in set(mydict).intersection(wordlist):`. Don't use `dict` as a variable name, as it collides with the `dict` builtin

Comment: In python3 that becomes `for word in mydict.keys() & wordlist:` which is even nicer since it doesn't need to create a set from `mydict`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

no. `foo in mydict` is in fact **a lot faster** than `foo in keys_list`, since `dict`s are hash tables, so finding the element inside it is `O(1)`. While foo in `keys_list` would be `O(n)` (slower as the number of keys grows bigger)

But you could always test yourself:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "x = range(1000)" "15 in x"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.311 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "x = dict.fromkeys(xrange(1000))" "15 in x"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0515 usec per loop
```

So checking directly on the `dict` for 1000 elements is one order of magnitude faster, not considering the time of the `.keys()`

Answer (score 5):

Actually, builtin dicts just call their `__contains__` which directly invokes the C function `dict_has_key` which is very fast.  So, doing it the first way is better because it doesn't force you to evaluate the entire sequence of keys within your dict as calling `keys()` does.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading, because *being in C* is not the reason that dicts are faster, since lists are also written in C. The dict algorithm is a hash table and that's what really makes it faster than checking inside a list (regardless of the language used to implement it)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  no, more like `__contains__`, which is O(1) (i.e., cheap).

Comment: (__contains__ is O(1) *for dicts* as others point out.  __contains__ on a list is O(n) amortized)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're actually trying to iterate over the intersection of the set of words
in "# long list of words" and the set of keys in the dictionary.  So use the built-in sets and its overloading of the `&` operator for intersections:

```
for word in set(some_dict) & set(wordlist):
    # do something
```

Comment: I realize I'm not answering the question regarding optimization and it's possible that, with very long lists and large dictionaries, then having Python create sets from each might be expensive.  However, it's unlikely.  First try to represent your code at the highest level supported by the language.  Then measure the performance and gauge it against your requirements.  Then optimize only as necessary.

Comment: (Arg! this is what I get for trying to answer a question on SO while trying to leave for work):  If your data sets are really large enough that the built-in set support is a performance limiting factor, you might want to consider offloading the set operations to MySQL or PostgreSQL (or any other SQL RDBMS).  The same principles apply and SQL's query semantics are based on set operations.

Comment: If you call the `intersection()` method instead of using `&`, you can pass any iterable as the parameter. eg `myset.intersection(mylist)`

Answer (score 1):

Just based on simple experimentation with code like:

```
_w= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
d= {}
w= []
for k in xrange(123):
    for word in _w:
        wk= word+ str(k)
        d[wk]= k
        w.append(wk)

def m1():
    for word in w:
        if word in d:
            pass

def m2(n= 1):
    dk= d.keys()
    for word in w:
        if word in dk:
            pass
```

and timings:

```
In []: len(w)
Out[]: 5
In []: %timeit m1()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 657 ns per loop
In []: %timeit m2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 us per loop

In []: len(w)
Out[]: 615
In []: %timeit m1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.2 us per loop
In []: %timeit m2()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop
```

The conclusion will be that m1() is a clear winner (as expected ;-).

OK, this is not really a proof (in a strict sense) of the superiority of `m1()`. There still exist a slight chance that someone will figure out a set of keys where `m1()` and `m2()` execution times are near each other (but I can't figure out any case where `m1()` would be actually much worse than `m2()`). In practice `m1()` approach allways wins. It's allways engouraged to try out first hard facts of the alternative approaches, then if something contradicts your expectations you'll be more prepared to find why it happens.